# Corona composer.gotoScene() does not reset my scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am pretty new to Corona. I have a button that triggers the following code:

```
local options =
    {
      effect = "fade",
      time = 400,
      params = {
        loadFromFile = true,
        fileName = "level1",
        level = levelParams
      }
    }
    composer.gotoScene( "view1", options)
```

When I finish the level and click this button again, the "view1" scene is in the same state. How do I reset it quickly? Like creating an entirely new scene object?

I tried using `composer.removeScene()` and purge, but nothing happens. Even non-graphic element stay the same, like scores and stuff.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Answer (score 2):

You create objects in

```
function scene:create( event )
```

then if you want them to change everytime you go away and come back, you should manipulate your objects under:

```
function scene:show( event )
```

There is an example under welcome screen>interface>composer in Corona SDK.

Comment: I had a problem with a scrolling background and this answer helped, but why do we have to do that if we keep deleting the objects (removeScene) and creating them at their original location every time we time we reload?

Comment: I like to spend time to answer you accurately. However, till I find that time, my guess is removeScene does not delete or destroy any object but hides/or moves them somewhere you dont see. Therefore, you still have the objects somewhere. You can check yourself by checking the obj.x or obj.y. If it returns nil then it is deleted otherwise you can get a clue to find out what is happening.